How to remove the non numeric values from a column in pandas
I have stumbled upon this problem. This is random data set from web about the movies and their budgets, revenue etc. The budget column in the data set has velues like Released, Language etc in it. I had tried the below solution but it does not seem to work.
movies['Budget']=movies['Budget'].str.replace(r'^[a-zA-Z]+$','')
I even tried a custome function but could not figure out whats wrong in this either.
def removecharacters(row):
row=str(row)
listt=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o',
'p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F',
'G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
for i in row:
if i in listt:
row.replace(i,'')
return row
Is there any other solution for this. I am a beginner and self-taught . What is wrong with the above stated solutions. Kindly help on this.

Convert to numeric with pd.to_numeric(df['you_col'], errors='coerce'), which will only keep the valid numbers. If this doesn't work for you, provide a [mre].

If you want to keep the numeric substrings, rather use extract
